# Default value for p:selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, xhtml, selectonemenu

I have a `p:selectOneMenu` dynamically populated by items from a controller class, like:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="state" value="#{ideaController.selected.state}" 
        required="true"
        requiredMessage="#{bundle.The} '#{bundle.State}' #{bundle.FieldIsRequired}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{ideaController.states}" 
            var="stateItem" 
            itemValue="#{stateItem}" 
            itemLabel="#{stateItem}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

But the first value is the first element in the list.

How can I set one value to be default?

Comment: Set value of `ideaController.selected.state` to whatever you want in your bean initialization

Comment: why give -1 to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the selected default value by setting the `selected` field on your `@PostConstruct` method in the backing bean (in `ideaController`)